# Save complex JSON object in CoreData

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm very new with Objective C and I inherited a project to learn and expand from. The end goal is to move to Swift in the long run, but for now I need to continue with Obj C.

I have a very large and complex JSON of roughly 4000 lines of variables and sub objects.

In Android I am able to easily deserialise this JSON to an object which can be saved easily with Room by essentially converting complex parts into separate JSON strings and deserialising them all when needed.

How should I approach this in Obj C? I found https://quicktype.io which allowed me to easily get a generated class for the JSON structure, so that part is done.

I need to save this data in CoreData and then retrieve all of it when needed. I don't need to get specific parts of the data, so it doesn't matter if it comes to saving the whole thing as a String.

Is there a way to easily generate table entities based on a class, or should I just mash it together as a String? What is the best way here?

Sorry that I can't give any code examples, because I don't have much to go on.

Comment: why do you need CoreData for that? if saving it as an `NSString` is good enough then save it into the _.../Document/_ folder as a file; you can find gazillion examples of, even on this site, how to do it.

Comment: The project already utilises CoreData for storing other data. I will be saving multiple of these complex JSON objects, so I don't think saving in a file is really a good solution for this. Should maybe have mentioned that.

Comment: I'd start with placing the string in core data, since that's the easiest.  See how that works and go from there.

Comment: If you aren't interested in deserializing the json, not only saving it as a string is the easiest, but it is also the best way to do it without the risk of missing out chunks of data due to errors in (de)serialization management. So you can just create a simple table with just a couple columns and populate it with your full jsons.

Comment: @danh & il3v I ended up just saving it as an NSString an deserialising it later. Thanks for the suggestion. :)